# Enrich data in streaming with apache beam and datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm working with google dataflow (python) to try enriching data comming from pubsub and insert into big query.

This is a high-level Diagram of the solution: [image]

I've worked with databrick and I'm trying to do the similitude but I'm getting a bad performance so far.

I'm using a datastore conection inside a ParDo to query and after another pardo to update the datastore.

How Could I do this to get a better performance?

The datastore has only 1 kind and the process of enrich consist on enrich the message receive with the last information saved and update the entity with the information that is being processing.

Thanks for the help!

Edit 1:
This is one of the ParDo function to query information from datastore

```
    def process(self, element):
        from google.cloud import datastore

        logging.info(f"Enriching {element.get('deviceId')}")

        datastore_client = datastore.Client()
        datastore_kind = "Device"

        key = datastore_client.key(datastore_kind, element['deviceId'])
        result = datastore_client.get(key)

        mapper = self.SensorToDatastoreMapper()
        should_update, mapped_data = mapper.map_record_to_entity(element, result)

        element.update(mapped_data)
```

Comment: Can you provide relevant for your code for the ParDo queries for Datastore that could possibly be affecting the performance? Also if possible, can you provide what kind of data is being processed? Just so this could be easily reproduced by the community.